# mp3 music loop in python for raspberry pi

Tags: python, loops, mp3

i'm new to python and this forum, but i've a little problem that someone may be able to help with? i'm creating a scene for a charity event, where I want my pi to control pneumatic rams, music and other electrical items, like motors.

I have music playing which will be interrupted by the operation of a switch/button, and that will start the sequence of events with the electronics and mechanics, the problem I have is there is an mp3 file playing at the start whilst waiting for a GPIO input which interrupts the mp3, that's fine unless there isn't an input in which case when the mp3 file finishes it just sits there waiting for the GPIO input.

I would like it to loop the mp3 file so that its not just waiting in silence, any help would be appreciated? the file is the first mp3 file, named "Noddy"

```
try:
    count=10
    while (count>0):
    print 'the count is:', count

os.system('mpg123 -q Make\ Way\ for\ Noddy.mp3 &')
GPIO.wait_for_edge(21, GPIO.FALLING)
subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
print "\nFalling edge detected. Now your program can continue with"
print "whatever was waiting for a button press."
# gpio 20 to open and close car doors while lightshow is running
#     GPIO.output(20, 0)
red_led.blink(5, 5, 5)
subprocess.call("sudo python synchronized_lights.py --
file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/Happy\ Birthday\ Emma.mp3",         
shell=True)
# gpio 20 to stop open and close of car doors
#     GPIO.output(20, 1)

os.system('mpg123 -q Make\ Way\ for\ Noddy.mp3 &')
GPIO.wait_for_edge(21, GPIO.FALLING)
subprocess.call(['killall', 'mpg123'])
print "\nFalling edge detected. Now your program can continue with"
print "whatever was waiting for a button press."
# gpio 20 to open and close car doors while lightshow is running
GPIO.output(20, 0)
red_led.blink(5, 5, 5)
subprocess.call("sudo python synchronized_lights.py --
file=/home/pi/lightshowpi/music/sample/Happy\ Birthday\ Lucy.mp3",        
shell=True)
# gpio 20 to stop open and close of car doors
GPIO.output(20, 1)
count= count-1
except KeyboardInterrupt:
GPIO.cleanup()       # clean up GPIO on CTRL+C exit
GPIO.cleanup()           # clean up GPIO on normal exit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily play music in loops with PyGame, which is pre-installed in the Pi I believe:

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("myFile.wav")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1) # note -1 for playing in loops
# do whatever
# when ready to stop do:
pygame.mixer.pause()
```

If you want to unpause:

```
pygame.mixer.unpause()
```